# OpenXML SDK Inject VBA into excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk, vba

I can successfully inject a piece of VBA code into a generated excel workbook, but what I am trying to do is use the Workbook_Open() event so the VBA code executes when the file opens.  I am adding the sub to the "ThisWorkbook" object in my xlsm template file.  I then use the openxml productivity tool to reflect the code and get the encoded VBA data.

When the file is generated and I view the VBA, I see "ThisWorkbook" and "ThisWorkbook1" objects.  My VBA is in "ThisWorkbook" object but the code never executes on open.  If I move my VBA code to "ThisWorkbook1" and re-open the file, it works fine.  Why is an extra "ThisWorkbook" created?  Is it not possible to inject an excel spreadsheet with a Workbook_Open() sub? Here is a snippet of the C# code I am using:

```
private string partData = "...";  //base 64 encoded data from reflection code
//open workbook, myWorkbook
VbaProjectPart newPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<VbaProjectPart>("rId1");
System.IO.Stream data = GetBinaryDataStream(partData);
newPart.FeedData(data);
data.Close();
//save and close workbook
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Within the VBA editor, when you right-click on ThisWorkbook and ThisWorkbook1, does either have the **Remove ThisWorkbook...** selection grayed out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my research there isn't a way to insert the project part data in a format that you can manipulate in C#. In the OpenXML format, the VBA project is still stored in a binary format. However, copying the `VbaProjectPart` from one Excel document into another should work. As a result, you'd have to determine what you wanted the project part to say in advance.

If you are OK with this, then you can add the following code to a template Excel file in the 'ThisWorkbook' Microsoft Excel Object, along with the appropriate Macro code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Run "Module1.SomeMacroName()"
End Sub
```

To copy the `VbaProjectPart` object from one file to the other, you would use code like this:

```
public static void InsertVbaPart()
{
    using(SpreadsheetDocument ssDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("file1.xlsm", false))
    {
        WorkbookPart wbPart = ssDoc.WorkbookPart;
        MemoryStream ms;
        CopyStream(ssDoc.WorkbookPart.VbaProjectPart.GetStream(), ms);

        using(SpreadsheetDocument ssDoc2 = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("file2.xlsm", true))
        {
            Stream stream = ssDoc2.WorkbookPart.VbaProjectPart.GetStream();
            ms.WriteTo(stream);
        }
    }
}

public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[short.MaxValue + 1];
    while (true)
    {
        int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (read <= 0)
            return;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I should also add that after writing I came across a platform called [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/). It's designed specifically for interacting with OpenXML Excel files and is very intuitive, it may also help.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the other answers still resulted in the duplicate "Worksheet" object. I used a similar solution to what @ZlotaMoneta said, but with a [different syntax found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728037/2912011):

```
List<VbaProjectPart> newParts = new List<VbaProjectPart>();
using (var originalDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("file1.xlsm"), false))
{
    newParts = originalDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<VbaProjectPart>().ToList();

    using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("file2.xlsm", true))
    {
        document.WorkbookPart.DeleteParts(document.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<VbaProjectPart>());

        foreach (var part in newParts)
        {
            VbaProjectPart vbaProjectPart = document.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<VbaProjectPart>();
            using (Stream data = part.GetStream())
            {
                vbaProjectPart.FeedData(data);
            }                    
        }

        //Note this prevents the duplicate worksheet issue
        spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.WorkbookProperties.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify "codeName" attribute in the "xl/workbook..xml" object
After feeding the VbaProjectPart with macro. Add this code:

```
var workbookPr = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<WorkbookProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
workbookPr.CodeName = "ThisWorkBook";
```

After opening the file everything should work now.

So, to add macro you need to:

1. Change document type to macro enabled
2. Add VbaProjectPart and feed it with earlier created macro
3. Add workbookPr codeName attr in xl/workbook..xml with value "ThisWorkBook"
4. Save as with .xlsm ext.