# Copy vba code to another xlsm file using Open XML from a template xlsm file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, openxml-sdk, vba

I use this code to add VbaPart of the template xlsm file into another.
When I open the vb section duplicate entries get added for each sheet as well as the "ThisWorkBook".

Below is the screen shot of how it looks in the developer tab [image]

And below is the code that I use:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(convertDocumentFile, true))
{
    VbaProjectPart extendedPart = FindPart(myDoc);

    if (extendedPart != null)
      myDoc.DeletePart(extendedPart);
    if (vbaPart != null)
      myDoc.WorkbookPart.AddPart<VbaProjectPart>(vbaPart);
}

private static VbaProjectPart FindPart(SpreadsheetDocument mainPart)
{
    if (mainPart != null)
    {
        foreach (IdPartPair partPair in mainPart.WorkbookPart.Parts)
        {
            if (partPair.OpenXmlPart.RelationshipType == _wnsRelationShip.NamespaceName)
            {
               return partPair.OpenXmlPart as VbaProjectPart;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where the variable "convertDocumentFile" is the file where the vbaProject part needs to be added and the "vbaPart" is the vbaProjectPart from the template.

Answer (score 2):

The reason my code did not execute was that the "CodeName" attribute was missing when I converted to xlsm format hence I need to add the following code:

```
myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.WorkbookProperties.CodeName = "ThisWorkbook";
```

After pointing to the correct workbook, the vb code executed correctly.