# C# OpenXML Word - How to create a VBA macro?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to create a macro in a new dotm word file created with OpenXML. I guess I have to add a VBAProjectPart but I can not go on.

The macro is stored in a string variable : for example

```
    string tmpMacro = "Private Sub Add_Pages()\nDim tmpPages As Integer\ntmpPages = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)\nSelection.EndKey Unit:= wdStory\nDo While Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) < 10\nSelection.InsertBreak(wdPageBreak)\nLoop\nEnd Sub";

    WordprocessingDocument tmpWD = WordprocessingDocument.Create("myDoc.docm", DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.MacroEnabledDocument);
    MainDocumentPart tmpWMP = tmpWGD.AddMainDocumentPart();

    tmpMDP.Document = new Document(new Body());

    tmpWD.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

In OpenXML, macros are a combination of binary format and XML relation files.

To verify this for yourself, create a new Word/Excel file, create a new macro, and save it as a macro-enabled document/workbook. Close the file and rename it to end with `.zip`.

In the main directory, you will find the file `[Content_Types].xml`, inside of which there are two relation pointers:

1. `<Default Extension="bin" 
             ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.vbaProject"/>`
2. `<Override PartName="/word/vbaData.xml" 
              ContentType="application/vnd.ms-word.vbaData+xml"/>`

To follow these files, locate `word/vbaData.xml`, inside of which there will be something like:

```xml
<wne:vbaSuppData ...namespaces ommitted... >
    <wne:mcds>
        <wne:mcd wne:macroName="PROJECT.NEWMACROS.MACRO1" 
                 wne:name="Project.NewMacros.Macro1" 
                 wne:bEncrypt="00" 
                 wne:cmg="56"/>
    </wne:mcds>
</wne:vbaSuppData>
```

This is shows that there is some macro named `Project.NewMacros.Macro1`, but little else. So let's look inside of `word/_rels/document.xml.rels`:

```xml
<Relationships ...namespaces ommitted...>
    <Relationship Id="rId1"
                  Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/vbaProject" 
                  Target="vbaProject.bin"/>
    ...other relationships ommitted...
</Relationships>
```

This points to `word/vbaProject.bin`, which is a binary file format.

If you need to add this macro programmatically (e.g. you cannot set everything else up, and add the macro manually), then you could create the macro in a one document manually, and then programmatically copy the binary stream from the manually created `vbaProject.bin` file into a new `vbaProject.bin` file.

If you decide to follow the stream copy approach, [the answer to this question includes a snippet demonstrating one way to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707228/openxml-sdk-inject-vba-into-excel-workbook).