# Injecting VBA As Text Into A PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, python-pptx

I think the answer to this will be "no" but it doesn't hurt to ask - and get people thinking.

I'd like to be able to **programmatically** add VBA as a text string to a PowerPoint presentation I'm creating with python-pptx.

I know I can confect the XML to create a button that, when clicked, runs a macro that already exists in the .pptm file.

Because the macro is stored compiled I don't think I can inject it **as text** programmatically. (I checked the format of a .pptm file with a "Hello World" macro in and there is an extra file in it with non-text material in.)

I also don't know if I can write a .pptm (macro-enabled .pptx) file with python-pptx.

So, Has anyone experimented with this?

The best I think I might be able to do - in md2pptx - is allow the user to add buttons that call pre-existing macros in the template file when clicked on. Unless the user builds their own template file off one I supply I don't think that enables me to add general function (such as deleting the first slide or note taking).

Comment: It would probably take a lot more to do that just *as text*. This is the only thing I could find that may point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707228/openxml-sdk-inject-vba-into-excel-workbook